# Node.js http-server and a rewrite rule

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy, httpserver

I'm using the node.js module http-server for developing an AngularJS application. Now I want to add a rewrite rule for this server: Every request with the pattern:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/*
```

should be redirected to

```
http://apiserver/api/*
```

All other request should be handled by http-server. But I'm not very sure what the best solution is here. I don't want to have an extra Node.js script. I just want to start one server. Is that possible? Is http-proxy a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track. Personally, I would use Nginx over node-http-proxy. All you have to do is install `nginx` (assuming under Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

now open your `nginx` settings file

```
sudo rvim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/!? (whatever that is under sites-enabled)
```

and configure your paths. You will setup two upstream and one redirect route to  apiserver/api/*, and proxy the rest to localhost:8000. For a more detailed guide, check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html